# windows phone 8.1 silverlight c#

Tags: c#, xaml

I am developing an application for windows phone 8.1 and I am new to developing mobile applications. Can someone please tell me how to get the name of all the folders in the picture library and use them in a comboBox for the user to select. And show all the pictures as a photo viewer inside the application.

Comment: This is a pretty broad question. You should break it down into multiple questions. And for each question, post the research you have done into solving it yourself, along with some code samples.

Comment: oh okay, actually I know what I want but I don't know where to start from so even if you could give me some direction to follow for accessing Picture Library and loading all the picture into the app  that would be great. because I have been wasting my time searching here and there but couldn't find anything that works.

Comment: Have you checked out the Windows 8.1 sample applications? https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Windows-Phone-81-samples-08631ca7 I'm sure there would be a sample app in there which demonstrates the use of listing pictures on a folder. There may be sample app which demonstrates the use of a combo box as well.

Comment: I checked all the samples they are really good. and Thank you for that but there isn't any sample that tells how to show photos like a photo gallery application.

Comment: okay now I know how to use file open picker to pick a single file or multiple files but I want to pick a folder and then get all the pictures inside that folder and show all those pictures in in the application.